# Moving a "falling" CCSprite according to acceleration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am using this code to move a "falling" sprite according to the acceleration of the UIDevice.
It works nice, but is very laggy, meaning that there are jumps between the positions of the sprite.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    if(paused)
        return;
    directionPoint.x += acceleration.x * 100;
}
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    if(paused)
        return;
    directionPoint.y = -500*dt;
    CGPoint playerDestinationPoint = player.position;
    playerDestinationPoint.x += directionPoint.x;
    playerDestinationPoint.y += directionPoint.y;
    if(playerDestinationPoint.x < player.contentSize.width/2) {
        playerDestinationPoint.x = player.contentSize.width/2;
    }
    else if(playerDestinationPoint.x > ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - play    er.contentSize.width/2)) {    
        playerDestinationPoint.x = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - player.contentSize.width/2;
    }
    [player setPosition:playerDestinationPoint];

    directionPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

I tried to use CCMoveTo this way:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    if(paused)
    return;
    [player stopAllActions];
    directionPoint.y = -500*dt;
    CGPoint playerDestinationPoint = player.position;
    playerDestinationPoint.x += directionPoint.x;
    playerDestinationPoint.y += directionPoint.y;
    if(playerDestinationPoint.x < player.contentSize.width/2) {
        playerDestinationPoint.x = player.contentSize.width/2;
    }
    else if(playerDestinationPoint.x > ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - player.contentSize.width/2)) {
        playerDestinationPoint.x = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize].width - player.contentSize.width/2;
    }
    id actionMoveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:dt position:playerDestinationPoint];
    [player runAction:actionMoveTo];

    directionPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

but the sprite won't move at all. Any hints?

MfG,

SideSwipe

Comment: what happen if you write  directionPoint.x += acceleration.x * 500; or more?

Comment: the sprite won't even fall down, it doesnt move at all. even if i set `directionPoint.y = -50000*dt;`

Answer (score 0):

In your first in your update method try:

```
    playerDestinationPoint.x += directionPoint.x*dt;
```

Since the dt interval can change depending on performance.